# How to compile a .cu with dynamic parallelism?

Tags: c++, cuda, dynamic-parallelism

I have 2 cpp files *setup* and *functions*, 6 .cu files *main*, *flood*, *timestep*, *discharge*, *continuity* and *copy*.
I'm trying to compile this to the main call the cpp files and so the flood kernel *global* and then flood call timestep, discharge, continuity and copy kernels all *device*.

Something like this:

Main
~functions
~setup
~flood
~~timestep
~~discharge
~~continuity
~~copy

I'm using a GK110 board with CUDA 5.5, but i don't know how to compile in separate sources (I got an error, that device functions requires separation compile mode).
I'm also dont know how to use -dc or -rtc={true} and flags for dynamic parallelism.

I tried to do this, but doesn't work:

```
g++  -c functions.cpp -std=c++0x 
g++  -c setup.cpp -std=c++0x  
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -dc timestep.cu copy.cu continuity.cu discharge.cu
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -dlink timestep.o copy.o continuity.o discharge.o -o link.o -lcudadevrt
nvcc -dc flood.cu -arch sm_35
```

When i reach de fifth line I got the error message that the device function call cannot be configured.

Someone can help me?

Comment: You know there is CUDA [online documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html), and [code samples](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#axzz2z0cavESl) including dynamic parallelism codes with makefiles that show how to compile?

Comment: I'll see this. I had found only for 5.0 and the example there was not helpful. Was only for a simple case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
g++  -c functions.cpp -std=c++0x 
g++  -c setup.cpp -std=c++0x  
nvcc timestep.cu copy.cu continuity.cu discharge.cu flood.cu -arch=sm_35 -lcudadevrt -rdc=true -c
nvcc timestep.o copy.o continuity.o discharge.o flood.o -arch=sm_35 -lcudadevrt -dlink -o dlink.o 
g++ functions.o steup.o dlink.o -o a.out -std=c++0x -L/<path>/cuda/lib<64,32> -lcudart -lcudadevrt
```

Comment: I do this, but included main.cu in the nvcc lines, but still have an error. ( a device call cannot be confiured in the line where my kernel - flood - call the other kernel - discharge -).

Comment: The device call cannot be configured is probably a syntax error in your code, not a problem with your compile sequence.  Do you have a function defined somewhere like `__device__ void myfunction(...)` that you are trying to call from host code like `myfunction<<<...>>>(...);` ?

Comment: I put all .cu files in one and leftonly my functions.cpp separate. Doing this I was able to complile making a makefile. And the __device__ functions doesn't work, but converting to __global__ yes.

Comment: Couldyou show your newest error of compilation?